# How to stop npm from compiling every keystroke in visual studio code?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, visual-studio-code

I am following a course to learn angular/node/npm, but I couldn't find a way to stop npm from compiling my source code for every keystroke in vs-code. I thought, it is because of Auto-save, but my vs-code is not set for auto-save.

- How can I disable npm for auto-compile?
- How can I invoke npm for a manual compile?

Comment: I'm assuming that the Angular App is built using Angular CLI. If that's the case, most probably you have the built setup that came with the scaffold that AngularCLI created for you. In that case, Webpack will compile your source file only on Save and not for every keystroke. Not sure what gives you a feeling that it is compiled on every keystroke. Don't you think it would make this compilation process extremely heavy?

Comment: are you using Angular-CLI or webpack?

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to get rid of unnecessary compilation. Yes, it is built with Angular CLI and found out that the settings.json states `files.autoSave":"AfterDelay"`. I have changed it and it is not compiling for every keystroke now, yeay! But, isn't there a "compile on-demand" possibility.  Probably, I should define a task for that. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: Just change it to "files.autoSave": "off", (which is the default).  So your compilation should now only be triggered when you save..  What did you change it to?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have the "autosave" turned on in the Visual Studio Code.

In VS Code just go to :

Settings --> Commonly User --> File: Auto Save -->  select "off"

Comment: For some reason this turned itself on for me as well!

Comment: @BrokenGlass, It was happening in 3-4 computers, I believe it was the updates.

Comment: Thank you, it was annoying to try to make small changes in my scss files based on the testing I did in chrome dev tools elements, only to have the recompile erase everything. Easy fix.

Answer (score 3):

It's not anything related to Visual Studio Code , it's feature called HotModuleReplacement

just do the below when you run

```
ng serve --live-reload false
```